# map shape to another button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path

```
<Path Data="M0.5,0 L0.5,1 M0,0.5 L1,0.5"
      StrokeThickness="4"
      Stretch="Fill"
      Stroke="Blue" />
```

This will draw a plus sign on a button if the button is the only thing in window,
but how can one map the path to this button?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BT_SIGN" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Grid Cursor="None" Margin="0,0,1.333,0">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E8CF3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
<Button           
        Grid.Column="3" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="44.8" 
        Width="75.2" 
        Margin="22.32,24.6,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Template="{DynamicResource BT_SIGN}">
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i.e. add a `<ContentPresenter />` to the template and set the `Content` property to your `Path`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BT_SIGN" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid Cursor="None" Margin="0,0,1.333,0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1E8CF3" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button           
    Grid.Column="3" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="44.8" 
    Width="75.2" 
    Margin="22.32,24.6,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Template="{DynamicResource BT_SIGN}">
        <Path Data="M0.5,0 L0.5,1 M0,0.5 L1,0.5"
            StrokeThickness="4"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Blue" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Path of that specific button inside the button markup.

```
<Button           
    Grid.Column="3" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="44.8" 
    Width="75.2" 
    Margin="22.32,24.6,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Template="{DynamicResource BT_SIGN}">

    <Path Data="M0.5,0 L0.5,1 M0,0.5 L1,0.5"
  StrokeThickness="4"
  Stretch="Fill"
  Stroke="Blue" />

</Button>
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But since I didn't have your Template, I did not set any template to the button. Can you post the code to your Template?

Comment: Look at mm8 answer. You were missing the <ContentPresenter/> in your template.